# Lower case file extension in MS Paint

Tags: windows, microsoft-paint

How to make MS Paint (Windows XP) to use lower case file extensions when saving files? I mean setting the default behaviour when I don't enter the extension explicitly.

Comment: try to see questions of how to change default format in paint and apply it to your problem (perhaps creating a shortcut to mspaint with a blank image as parameter, that has lowercase file extension, can solve it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default extensions used in the standard Open/Save dialogs are controlled by each application.

In this case, unfortunately, they are hard-coded inside the MS Paint executable. There's no way to change them, except from hex-editing mspaint.exe (not for the faint of heart).

I would suggest using a file renaming utility to change the letter case of the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista they all default to lower-case. I'm guessing you want this because you are going to use the files on the web or on a Linux box? If not, windows is case insensitive so it doesn't make a real difference apart from aesthetics.

**Note, don't do these unless you really know what your doing**

Try searching your registry for 'BMP' and/or 'paint' is it could be a registry setting.

If it isn't, then it would be set in the mspaint exe or associated DLL and would require a Hex-editor to change it.

Comment: "I'm guessing you want this because you are going to use the files on the web " Yes, that is my goal. So as I see, the only way to do it is by making change to paint executable.

Answer (score -2):

. Right click on the said file
. click on rename
. rename the extension .JPG to .jpg 
. refresh the page and yiu should have a lower extension

**or**

. Open document in paint
. Save as name.jpg in the filename box
. refresh page and you are done