# How to set default file format for MS Paint

Tags: file-format, microsoft-paint

I'm using MS Paint on WinXP at work, for capturing simple screenshots.
Problem: MS Paint always wants to save in BMP format.
**How can I set PNG to be Paint's default file-saving format?**

*Note: Suggestions about other software are irrelevant. I know there are many other software tools available. But I'm asking specifically about MS Paint.*

Comment: Doesn't really help you if you are on XP, but Paint on Vista and 7 both use PNG as the default save format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible, based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/105542/lower-case-file-extension-in-ms-paint/105558#105558) to a related question. It would be good if someone can confirm this.

Comment: see other related questions. it is possible doing a shortcut with a blank image in format you want as parameter.